How does the instantaneous radiative forcing occur?
I am reading chapter 8 of the IPCC AR5 [Myhre et al. 2013] and am confused about the instantaneous radiative forcing [IRF].
From my understanding, the idea is that a greenhouse gas is introduced into the atmosphere, and its impact on the radiative flux at the tropopause is found via two radiative transfer calculations.
I understand the idea of radiative forcing = change in radiative flux, but how exactly does the greenhouse gas achieve this? I think each greenhouse gas molecule can absorb and emit radiation at given wavenumbers. So at a given altitude at a given atmospheric temperature [which is fixed since this is the IRF] the molecules should absorb and emit the same amount[*] hence there should be no change to the radiative flux at that altitude. Hence no IRF.
[*] I may be wrong about this point.

Greenhouse gas molecules absorb radiation in a wavelength where most of the radiation comes from below (namely, the earth surface), but re-emit in a random direction. As a consequence, a photon that would have gone out to space is re-emitted in random directions and so has a probability of 1/2 to get back to Earth. In other words, it reduces the outbound energy flux and increases the inbound energy flux, compared to not having (or having less) greenhouse gases around.
